# Calculating running (cumulative) sum with start and end dates over time

Tags: looker-studio

I'm looking for a way to calculate recurring revenue over time in a time plot where the X-axis is the date and Y-axis is the total amount of revenue (sum). The question we're trying to answer is "**At any given point in time, what is the total amount of revenue coming in?**"

Every line in the source data has an account name, subscription type (new, renewal, expansion), annual subscription amount, service start date, and service end date.

[Sample of data below]

| Account | Type | Subscription Amount | Service Start | Service End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | New | $ 1000 | Jan 1, 2020 | Dec 31, 2021 |
| 002 | New | $ 2000 | Feb 1, 2020 | Jan 31, 2021 |
| 003 | New | $ 3000 | Apr 1, 2020 | Mar 1, 2022 |
| 001 | Expansion | $ 500 | May 1, 2020 | Dec 31, 2021 |
| 002 | Renewal | $ 2500 | Feb 1, 2021 | Jan 31, 2023 |
| 004 | New | $ 1000 | Mar 1, 2021 | Feb 28, 2023 |
| 002 | Expansion | $ 250 | Jun 1, 2021 | Jan 31, 2023 |
| 001 | Renewal | $ 1500 | Jan 1, 2022 | Dec 31, 2023 |

The main issue I'm running into is that **when using either running sum or "cumulative" under the time plot settings panel, the total will continue running on the X-axis regardless of the service end date**. This is a problem for situations like Account 002, which renews Feb 1st, 2021. Data Studio would (incorrectly) show an amount of $4500 for that account starting on Feb 1st -- where I want it to show only $2500 at that time.

Comparing what the data should be showing at any point in time vs. what actually happens:

| Date | Amount I want to see | What is currently calculated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2020 | $ 1000 | $ 1000 |
| Feb 1, 2020 | $ 3000 | $ 3000 |
| Apr 1, 2020 | $ 6000 | $ 6000 |
| May 1, 2020 | $ 6500 | $ 6500 |
| Feb 1, 2021 | $ 7000 | $ 9000 |
| Mar 1, 2021 | $ 8000 | $ 10,000 |
| Jun 1, 2021 | $ 8250 | $ 10,250 |
| Jan 1, 2022 | $ 8250 | $ 11,750 |
| Jan 1, 2023 | $ 5250 | $ 11,750 |

Is there a way to achieve this?

Ideally, the most elegant solution seems to be to tell the plot to only sum between dates (i.e. sum if "reported x-axis date" is between Service Start date and Service End date), but I don't know how to reference the X-axis value in a formula.

I have not yet tried blending the data but I'm thinking that may be another path forward as well?

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: as of now I cannot think of a way to achieve this solely by inbuilt studio blends/calculated fields. Hoping someone else would pitch in & offer a way to do it. if your backend source is sheets there's a way to add this extra column there itself via formula.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is exported from a CRM daily into Google sheets. I can’t manipulate it until it’s in data studio.